# How to protect Google's clientSecret and clientID in a WinRT application?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, oauth-2.0, winrt-xaml

I'm developing a WinRT application that makes use of the Google Tasks API. Currently, the ClientSecret and ClientID strings are embedded in the code. However, I've read that this should be avoided, as Windows 8 Apps can be easily reverse engineered.

So, what is a better way to keep these tokens secure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the apps can easily be reverse engineered it doesn't say much about the **security** of that *mobile* platform IMHO. (yes I realize Win8 is not just mobile but all the other vendors seem to be doing all they can to lock down the access)

Comment: not sure much about windows 8 but in desktop applications, to protect stuff like connection strings in the app.config you can encrypt it on installation [example article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15392/Implementing-Protected-Configuration-With-Windows) so maybe something similar?

Comment: From Google documentation, "Installed application" section: <<The client_id and client_secret obtained during registration are embedded in the source code of your application. In this context, the client_secret is obviously not treated as a secret.>> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: enz0, I'm not sure if something similar is available for WinRT... I guess Kiewic is right, there is no way around this, except for one: moving the logic to a webserver, and have the WinRT application ask my webserver to connect to google.

Comment: @Kiewic, you can put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google documentation, in the "Installed application" section:

> The client_id and client_secret obtained during registration are embedded in the source code of your application. In this context, the client_secret is obviously not treated as a secret.

Read more here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp